# System of $24$ variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Assume that $a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_{24}$ satisfy
$$a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_{24}=26$$$$a_1^2+a_2^2+\ldots+a_{24}^2=26$$$$\vdots$$$$a_1^{24}+a_2^{24}+\ldots+a_{24}^{24}=26$$
Find $a_1a_2⋯a_{24}$. How do I solve it? I know there is sone thing I am missing, nobody will solve the equations.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Newton-GirardFormulas.html

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$S_k(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_j^k$$
be the power sums and $\Pi_k(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ be the homogeneous symmetric polynomials in $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ having degree $k$. By the [Newton-Girard formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Newton-GirardFormulas.html) we have:
$$ S_1=\Pi_1,$$
$$ S_2 - S_1 \Pi_1= -2\Pi_2, $$
$$ S_3 - S_2 \Pi_1 + S_1\Pi_2 = 3\Pi_3, $$
$$\ldots $$
$$ S_{24}-S_{23}\Pi_1 +\ldots -S_1\Pi_{23} =-24\Pi_{24},$$
and we want to compute $\Pi_{24}$ from $S_1=S_2=\ldots=S_{24}=26$. That leads to:

$$-24\Pi_{24} = 26\left(1-\Pi_1+\Pi_2-\ldots-\Pi_{23}\right)=23\Pi_{23}-26\Pi_{23} $$
hence:
$$ \Pi_{24}=\frac{1}{8}\Pi_{23} $$
and going on:
$$ 23\Pi_{23} = 26(1-\Pi_1+\Pi_2-\ldots+\Pi_{22}) = -22\Pi_{22}+26\Pi_{22}$$
hence:
$$\Pi_{23}=\frac{4}{23}\Pi_{22} $$
and continuing this way we get:
$$ \Pi_{24} = \frac{3}{24}\cdot\frac{4}{23}\cdot\frac{5}{22}\Pi_{21} = \frac{3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot\ldots\cdot 25}{24!}\Pi_1=25\cdot 13 = \color{red}{325}.$$

Answer (score 0):

take
$$f(x)=(x-a_{1})(x-a_{2})\cdots (x-a_{24})=x^n-\sigma_{1}x^{n-1}+\sigma_{2}x^{n-2}-\cdots+\sigma_{24}$$
let
$$s_{k}=a^k_{1}+\cdots+a^k_{24}\Longrightarrow s_{k}=24,k=1,2,3\cdots,24$$
and use well identity:
$$S_{n}-\sigma_{1}S_{n-1}+\cdots+24\sigma_{24}=0$$
so 
$$1-\sigma_{1}+\sigma_{2}+\cdots+\sigma_{24}=0$$
so we have $f(1)=0$.
WLOG,Assmue that $a_{24}=1$

and use same methods,we have $a_{23}=a_{23}=\cdots=a_{1}=1$